# Chrome CSS transition + text shadow issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, transition

```
a {
    transition: text-shadow, 0.5s, ease;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow:  #343434 1px 1px 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow:
        #343434 1px 1px 1px,
        0 0 10px #fff,
        0 0 20px #fff,
        0 0 30px #fff,
        0 0 40px #ff00de,
        0 0 70px #ff00de,
        0 0 80px #ff00de,
        0 0 100px #ff00de,
        0 0 150px #ff00de;  
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

transition + text shadow works flawless with firefox, but not working with chrome, anyone know how to fix this?

Please open the following link with firefox then chrome, you will see the differences;

http://jsfiddle.net/tfKE8/

Thanks for help!

PS: I tried -webkit-transition, it won't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There might be a mistake in a syntax, try without commas:

```
transition: text-shadow 0.5s ease;
```

This gives a smooth transition in Chrome 30.0.1599.69.